# Fine-tuning NSTextField auto completion

Tags: cocoa, autocomplete, nstextfield, autosuggest, nssearchfield

I'm using NSControlTextEditingDelegate to auto complete what's
typed in a NSSearchField with custom suggestions I generate.
`complete:` message is sent to field editor
when text is changed.

Now I'd like to fine-tune the behavior of auto-completion and have it
working exactly as Google search text field works in Safari:

1. When two or more words (separated by spaces) are typed in NSTextField,
   location for NSRange passed in `control:textView:textView:completions:forPartialWordRange:
   indexOfSelectedItem:` starts after the last space typed.

   This means that if user types "San Fran" and Google APIs returns "San
   Francisco", choosing it from auto-complete list NSTextField value is
   replaced with "San San Francisco".

   A possible workaround consist in rebuilding NSArray containing completion
   and returning only the suffix of the actual suggestions,
   depending on charRange.location. This looks crappy (because auto-completion
   list now shows only part of the completion string), so I want to have
   `NSTextField` ignore spaces when requesting auto-completion.
2. Choosing an auto completion from list, default NSSearchField action is not
   sent. At the moment user need to choose an auto completion and then press
   enter to trigger search.

Comment: Running into the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a custom field editor rather than relying entirely on the delegate callbacks.

1) Override `rangeForUserCompletion` and adjust the returned value so it includes the text past the whitespace.

2) Override `insertCompletion:forPartialWordRange:movement:isFinal` and if isFinal is checked, do your accept processing.

Step (1) above will fix the range.  If you're also setting the index in `completionsForPartialWordRange` to fill the edit (or leaving it at the default 0), the spacebar, along with '/' and '.' will accept the currently selected line, even if what the user wanted was to just keep typing.  To work around that, in `insertCompletion:forPartialWordRange:movement:isFinal`, if isFinal is true, check `[NSApp currentEvent]` for those characters, and if they're found, skip out without processing it or calling super.

Comment: Custom field editor can be replaced by default one by returning subclass of NSTextView in windowWillReturnFieldEditor of NSWindowDelegate.